# How to stop a process in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, kill-process

I have some processes that are taking long time to terminate.

I had run q query that took 30 hours "I forgot about it" so I killed it using "kill id" but it has been trying to roll back for more than 30 hours already.

Can someone please tell me how can I force this to stop?

when I run this query

```
select
    p.spid
,   right(convert(varchar, 
            dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, P.last_batch, getdate()), '1900-01-01'), 
            121), 12) as 'batch_duration'
,   P.program_name
from master.dbo.sysprocesses P
where P.spid > 50
and      P.status not in ('background', 'sleeping')
and      P.cmd not in ('AWAITING COMMAND'
                    ,'MIRROR HANDLER'
                    ,'LAZY WRITER'
                    ,'CHECKPOINT SLEEP'
                    ,'RA MANAGER')
order by batch_duration desc
```

I get the following results

```
61  23:40:48.893    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                                                                                  
51  23:33:03.410    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                                                                                  
58  23:01:08.960    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                                                                                  
55  20:45:41.953    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                                                                                  
64  19:08:37.310    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                                                                                  
62  00:00:05.207    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query
```

When I run kill 61 I get the following
SPID 61: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.  (this has been the case for the past 24 hours!)

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The original query that was running for 30 hours. What was it actually doing?

Comment: it was a query the was reading data from excel file using openquery and inserting it into a temp table. the excel file has about 30 lines so it is very small. And I always run this query but never took long at all.   even if I just run a query to read the data from the file it will take forever. SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=E:\UploadFiles\;', 
                      'SELECT * from new.csv')

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks WHERE session_id = 61` return anything?

Comment: yes it does. it returns the task address and a wait time of 85753828

Comment: And what is the wait type?

Comment: Is there a blocking session id?

Comment: the resorce description is "External ExternalResource=MSQL_DQ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to kill all the processes, may be, the fastest way is:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Data base name] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

After that may be you want to go back to the previous database state:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Data base name] SET MULTI_USER
```

That is going to kill all the processes without restarting the server. If you want to kill a set of specific processes and "kill @spid" doesnt work I can only recomend you to use a DAC connection and see what happens.

Comment: This command will still simply try to kill the relevant sessions. It's easier than performing a bunch of KILL commands in a loop, but it amounts to the same thing, and will not be able to magically kill a session that is performing a rollback. This is intentional and is meant to protect your database - and which is why stopping the service is such a dangerous approach.

Comment: I executed the first query. When I tried to execute the second query I got the following error.   Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'MULTIUSER_USER'.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I did that on the wrong database. So Now I executed the first query on the database on where I used to create the temp tables but it is taking a while. Is this expected? or it should be quick alter?  thanks

Comment: No, like I said, this command can't complete until it kills all of the relevant processes. This is no different from you running kill over and over again - it will have to wait for the one that's in rollback/cancel to finish rolling back or canceling.

Comment: @Mike - I was just telling you the correct syntax to restore your database to multi user mode. I guess running `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` will still have to wait indefinitely on that hanging process.

Comment: Okay, So at this point I should do nothing and wait until this this done.... I will wait and update you after it is done. Thanks :)

Comment: I finally got it to work. I rebooted the server and that stopped processes. Note it was hanging because the server was running out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

You're just going to have to wait. Some people panic and pull the power cord, but this will likely just mean the rollback will start over once you restart the service.

You may want to look at this Connect item for potential workarounds (and confirmation that this is a known issue and won't likely be fixed any time soon):

[http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/187192/openquery-to-linked-server-hangs...](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/187192/)

As an aside, a few things about your query:

1. You should only be using `sysprocesses` if you are using SQL Server 2000 or older. From SQL Server 2005 on you should be using DMVs (e.g. `sys.dm_exec_requests`). The old `sys...` views still exist for backward compatibility only. **However**, in some cases, you may want to use it to determine the `waitresource` - it may provide information about the remote instance / session, depending on the linked server type, which may give you information you can use to kill the process on the other end. In your case this isn't relevant because the remote "server" is just a text file. Perhaps you can kill the task with Task Manager...
2. `spid > 50` is not a very foolproof way to identify non-system processes. The new DMVs, for example, allow you to identify user processes using `sys.dm_exec_sessions.is_user_process`.
3. [You should not `CONVERT(VARCHAR` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).
4. [You should not use shorthand like `ms` - if you mean `MILLISECOND`, type `MILLISECOND`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). And do you really need millisecond accuracy when measuring a query that has been running for 30 hours?
5. Be very careful with `'string delimited column aliases'` - this syntax is deprecated in some cases and also looks like a string literal to most readers. If you really want to delimit the alias (in this case you don't need to), use `[square brackets]`.
6. Your truncation of the time only makes little sense to me. If the query had been running for four days, you wouldn't know. Why not:

   ```
   ;WITH x AS 
   (
     SELECT 
       session_id, 
       command,
       [status],
       s = DATEDIFF(SECOND, start_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
     WHERE EXISTS 
     (
       SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
       WHERE session_id = r.session_id
       AND is_user_process = 1
     )
     AND start_time < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   )
   SELECT session_id, command, [status], s,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), s / 86400) + ' days '
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (s % 86400) / 3600) + ' hours '
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (s % 86400) % 3600 / 60) + ' minutes.'
   FROM x
   ORDER BY s DESC;
   ```

Comment: but this has been going for 24 hours!

Comment: @Mike well if it did 30 hours worth of work before you cancelled it, you should expect it will take *at least* 30 hours to undo it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Though it seems to have been hung waiting on `OLEDB` wait type for `23.8` hours and counting.

Comment: @MartinSmith interesting. Was it a linked server query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - From the comments under the question itself it uses `OPENROWSET` and the text driver.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2003

Comment: @Mike there is no such thing. Do you mean SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the ROLLBACK. You should try to avoid to start it instead. Do I understand there are 3 copies of the same code running  ???

Maybe you can use a SEMAPHORE check before running it. For example:

Check if a temp table exist before running the 30h code. If the table exists you don't run the code else you create the table THEN you run the code.